# Add UserControl from other thread

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I have my user control. I add a collection of these user controls (100 or over) to a panel. And this panel is in turn added to the main form. All this is done at run-time. 
Since there are so many user controls, my main form gets unresponsive until these user controls are added.

I'm wondering if I can add the panel to the form first and then from a separate thread create my user controls and add them to the same panel, so my main form is always available to the user. All my efforts result in:

> 'cross-thread operation not valid' error.

I'll be great full if someone can help me with this.

Here is what I am doing right now

```
void main(){
    MyPanel pnlObj = new MyPanel();
    this.Controls.Add(pnlObj);
}

Class MyPanel{

    public void Panel()
    {
        MyUserControl uc1 = new MyUserControl();
        MyUserControl uc2 = new MyUserControl();
        this.Add(uc1);
        this.Add(uc2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot work with visual elements in a non-UI thread, sorry for that.

But what you can do is to create the all the necessary data in the non-UI thread, and delegate creating the UI elements and updating the UI to the UI thread.

This would look like this:

```
// in background thread
ComputeDataSlowly();
MainForm.Invoke(() =>
{
    var control = CreateNewControlFromData();
    MainForm.Add(control);
});
```

Comment: Thanks but an example will be be more helpful.

Comment: @Zubair: well, maybe you can present an example of what you are going to achieve?

Comment: I've edited my original post so it may give you a general idea how I'm doing this right now.

Comment: @Zubair: Well, in the example you provided you don't actually need any background thread, you can add the controls from within the UI thread. Are there some really slow operations involved?

Comment: Values are fetched from the database for MyUserControl

Comment: @Zubair: okay, so you can fetch the database data in `ComputeDataSlowly()`. You'll need a reference to the main form in the background thread though.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if there is a solution to your problem. Only the GUI thread can update controls, so even if you do use an additional thread, you'd still have to forward the work of creating/adding the controls to the GUI thread via `Invoke/BeginInvoke`, which leads back to your original problem.